# how to publish to facebook wall, error 'session' cannot be null

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have integrated facebook into my app but am having trouble posting feed from my app to user's facebook wall. In this app a user logins into facebook and the app stores the access token and access expires in sharedpreferences

```
editor.putString("access_token", fb.getAccessToken());
editor.putLong("access_expires", fb.getAccessExpires());
```

then i use this method to access them when a user tries to share content from my app to facebook

```
sp = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    String access_token = sp.getString("access_token", null);
    long expires = sp.getLong("access_expires", 0);

    if (access_token != null) {

        fb.setAccessToken(access_token);
    }

    if (expires != 0) {

        fb.setAccessExpires(expires);
    }
```

on the share button i have this code

```
if (fb.isSessionValid()) {
            publishFeedDialog();

        }else{
//login into facebook
}
```

And the method am using to test this publish feature is

```
private void publishFeedDialog() {
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();

    //if (session != null) {
        Bundle params = new Bundle();
        params.putString("name", "Testing this app ");
        params.putString("caption",
                "Build great social apps and get more installs.");
        params.putString(
                "description",
                "The Facebook SDK for Android makes it easier and faster to develop Facebook integrated Android apps.");
        params.putString("link", "https://developers.facebook.com/android");
        params.putString("picture",
                "https://raw.github.com/fbsamples/ios-3.x-howtos/master/Images/iossdk_logo.png");
        WebDialog feedDialog = (new WebDialog.FeedDialogBuilder(
                ReportDetails.this, session, params))
                .setOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(Bundle values,
                            FacebookException error) {
                        if (error == null) {
                            // When the story is posted, echo the success
                            // and the post Id.
                            final String postId = values
                                    .getString("post_id");
                            if (postId != null) {
                                Toast.makeText(ReportDetails.this,
                                        "Posted story, id: " + postId,
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            } else {
                                // User clicked the Cancel button
                                Toast.makeText(ReportDetails.this,
                                        "Publish cancelled",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        } else if (error instanceof FacebookOperationCanceledException) {
                            // User clicked the "x" button
                            Toast.makeText(ReportDetails.this,
                                    "Publish cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                    .show();
                        } else {
                            // Generic, ex: network error
                            Toast.makeText(ReportDetails.this,
                                    "Error posting story",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }

                }).build();
        feedDialog.show();
    /*}else{
        Toast.makeText(this, "session is empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }*/
}
```

the Error am getting is

```
04-30 13:11:20.590: E/AndroidRuntime(23829): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-30 13:11:20.590: E/AndroidRuntime(23829): java.lang.NullPointerException: Argument      'session' cannot be null
04-30 13:11:20.590: E/AndroidRuntime(23829):    at com.facebook.internal.Validate.notNull(Validate.java:29)
04-30 13:11:20.590: E/AndroidRuntime(23829):    at com.facebook.widget.WebDialog$BuilderBase.<init>(WebDialog.java:482)
04-30 13:11:20.590: E/AndroidRuntime(23829):    at com.facebook.widget.WebDialog$FeedDialogBuilder.<init>(WebDialog.java:668)
04-30 13:11:20.590: E/AndroidRuntime(23829):    at com.jingo.willapps.helloworld.a.p.p.ReportDetails.publishFeedDialog(ReportDetails.java:485)
04-30 13:11:20.590: E/AndroidRuntime(23829):    at com.jingo.willapps.helloworld.a.p.p.ReportDetails.onOptionsItemSelected(ReportDetails.java:353)
04-30 13:11:20.590: E/AndroidRuntime(23829):    at com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockActivity.onMenuItemSelected(SherlockActivity.java:208)
04-30 13:11:20.590: E/AndroidRuntime(23829):    at com.actionbarsherlock.ActionBarSherlock.callbackOptionsItemSelected(ActionBarSherlock.java:604)
04-30 13:11:20.590: E/AndroidRuntime(23829):    at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockCompat.onMenuItemSelected(ActionBarSherlockCompat.java:516)
04-30 13:11:20.590: E/AndroidRuntime(23829):    at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:744)
04-30 13:11:20.590: E/AndroidRuntime(23829):    at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.view.menu.SubMenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(SubMenuBuilder.java:83)
04-30 13:11:20.590: E/AndroidRuntime(23829):    at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:148)
04-30 13:11:20.590: E/AndroidRuntime(23829):    at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:885)
```

so what could be the issue here

Comment: make sure your key is correct ...

Comment: The key is correct because i can post to the wall using the post dialog but cannot share a feed from my app